# JomSocial Tooltips

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, jomsocial

I have the Latest Members and Online Users modules enabled in my footer. However, the tooltips that appear on hover are about 200px to the right of where they should be. I am having trouble tracking down **where** the css is made that controls where the tooltips appear.

Does anyone know?

I should add that I am using JomSocial 3.1.1 and Joomla 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable issue is a conflict between your template and JomSocial template. You can debug it with a browser inspection tool, like Firefox's **Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools** (F12).

Both tools allows to explore each Html element and all the applied styles, even allowing to enable/disable each declaration.

Once you find the CSS style causing the conflict, you can add a new declaration in your template to fix it.

Comment: Firebug is excellent. Just right click the tooltips and choose Inspect element with firebug. I'd also like to recommend the WebDeveloper addon for firefox. It does very much the same thing as Firebug, but I find it easier to use in some situations. In WebDeveloper click on Information then Display Element Information then click on the tooltips.

Comment: I have not fixed the issue yet, but I have marked it the answer because at a browser width of < 700px, the tooltips appear fine, and then if I manually make the browser wider, the tooltips become increasingly out of place. This leads me to believe it is indeed a CSS conflict that can be resolved by modifying my own CSS. Thank you for your insight!